# Identify duplicated rows based on multiple columns and specific value in another column in very large matrix with for loop

Tags: r

I have a large matrix called `data` of 10,864 rows and 134 columns.

The first 4 columns are parameters which make every row unique. The data from 5th to 134th column for all rows are numbers between 1 and 20.

[image]

[image]

I am running a for loop in the matrix to insert `NA` into certain cells of the matrix. This needs to be done on the basis of unique values from Columns `OrgID`, `rank` and `scorei` only if value in same row for column `score(i+12) != 1`.

Hence, I run a `for loop` from column 5 to 134 and where there is duplication based on these three columns and value in `score(i+12)`column value is not equal to 1, I insert `NA` into that cell of matrix.

```
for(i in 5:ncol(data){
data[which(duplicated(data[,c(1,4,i)]) & (data[,i+12])!=1),i] <- "NA"
}
```

This code, however, gives the wrong output by inserting `NA` only where there is duplicated value on the basis of `1`st,`4`th and `i`th column i.e. equivalent result to running the following code:

```
for(i in 5:ncol(data){
    data[which(duplicated(data[,c(1,4,i)])),i] <- "NA"
    }
```

How do make it to perform the required operation only when value in column `score(i+12) !=1` in the duplicated rows.

To make it simpler to see the failed output, I have highlighted a few rows and the relevant columns to show how this works when applied to the column 118 i.e.`i =118` here.

[image]

For example, based on the above explained logic, there is duplication in `OrgID=5659`. The duplication based on OrgID, rank and score118 identifies these 2 rows with one row showing value in `score130=1`and other `score130=16`. Hence, in the row with `score130=16` should be now `NA` according to the logic. But this remains unchanged at `16`.

Comment: I have displayed a small demonstration in a few rows of the matrix of what the output is showing and explained where it is giving wrong result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try

```
for(i in 5:(ncol(data) - 12)) {
   inds <- duplicated(data[c(1,4,i)]) | duplicated(data[c(1,4,i)], fromLast = TRUE)
   data[inds & data[[i + 12]] != 1, i + 12] <- NA
}
```